# Maven dependency - questions

Tags: maven

I am currently new to Software field and I am into a Dev project and my questions are related to Maven.

My projectA has root pom.xml and many modules each with its own pom.xml.
Project B uses Project A as its dependency.

Questions:

D stands for Dependency

1. A module X has a dependency Y and the same Y with a new version has been used in root pom.xml so from where(D defined in module or  D defined in root pom)
   dependency will be called here? -- This is related to ProjA and its modules!!
2. If ProjB is using a dependency(with a new version) which is already being used in ProjA root Pom then from where( D defined in ProjA or D defined in ProjB) dependency is being called? -- This is related to ProjB using its dependency ProjA!!

This is quite confusing to me and the help here is appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: Could you please make your question more precise? I guess that B does not use A (as a whole) as dependency, but probably one or more modules of A. Furthermore, I guess that the root POM is the parent POM of the modules in the project. Then they would inherit dependencies from the root POM. The "From where" is also unclear to me? In a multi-module build, you can reference other modules, otherwise your dependencies are resolved through the local repository.

Comment: No.. ProjB uses ProjA dependency as  a whole. I have also re-framed the question. Kindly check and let me know if this requires any further details. Thanks!!

Comment: "ProjB uses ProjA dependency as a whole": Does it mean that ProjB uses the root POM of project A as dependency? Or what exactly do you mean? Is any `<dependencyManagement>` used, or just dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at the link below, maven uses a "nearest win" strategy. It means that the first one to be encountered by maven in the dependency tree will be picked.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

You can run the link exemple to see what version will be the one in your project.

Comment: Yeah..Thank u. I think I am quite convinced with ur reply here!! Thanks.